# A question about CALayer and UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, calayer

The object is to implement a semi-transparent layer which would slid out to collect user response when needed.  The semi-transparent layer would have some icons on it for the user to choose from.  Currently I am using a CALayer object which seems ok and it has some build in animation behavior.

But the problem is CALayer does not response to any touch events at all.  Now I am thinking that I should be using a UIView instead.  UIView inherits from UIResponder, so its objects are naturally capable of responding to users' events.

It's a decision between UIView and CALayer.  For the CALayer, I have done quite a bit of work on it and it looks quite ok except about the touch response that has to be added.  Or should I use a UIView as subview instead (since it has build-in touch respond) ?

Hope that somebody knowledgable on this could help ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to respond to user interaction, the best way is to use a `UIView`.  You could probably get it to work without one, but I wouldn't recommend it.

As for integrating your existing layer with the `UIView`, I'd create a subclass of `UIView` and override its `+layerClass` method to return the `Class` of your custom `CALayer`.  Alternatively, if you're not using a custom `CALayer` subclass (and there generally isn't a real need to create your own), you can do your custom drawing inside the `UIView`'s [`-drawLayer:inContext:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CALayer_class/Introduction/Introduction.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004500-CH1-SW50) method.

Comment: Thanks for your advice and explanation.  Guess I should be seriously considering to rework the portion with a UIView.  It's a difficult decision, but it would be a good learning experience.  Thanks ...